# How do I use picklist values as a number value?

Tags: apex, formula, custom-field

I have a picklist consist of {Low, Medium, High} and I want to use them in a report. But somehow I have to convert them to a number value like {1,2,3} to be able to calculate summary. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to do this for this one specific report, I would suggest [bucket fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_bucketing_overview.htm&language=en_US):

> Bucketing lets you quickly categorize report records without creating a formula or a custom field. For example, create a bucket field named Size based on the # Employees field. Then, create buckets that group records into “Large,” “Medium,” or “Small” ranges that you define. Bucket fields can be used like any other field to sort, filter, and group your report.

If this is required in more places than one, I would suggest creating a formula field (return type: number) using the Case() formula:

```
Case(MyField__c, 'Low', 1, 'Middle', 2, 'High', 3, 0)
```

Syntax may not be perfect as I just wrote that from memory, but it should get you close enough.

Comment: Great, please mark this post as the answer then.